# How to import data from a worksheet to the powerpivot from the same workbook

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I wants to import data from a worksheet in a workbook "\foo.xlsx" to powerpivot in the same workbook "\foo.xlsx".

when i try to give the connection to the same workbook its gives the error:

```
The file you have chosen is in use. Please close the file before you import.
```

Is there any way to solve this problem??!!

Thanks

Comment: show the code you use if you expect any help. let's make it clear- do you import to pp (which states in your question) or you export to pp (which is suggested by tag (excel-vba))??

Comment: I want to import to pp, not exporting to pp. i used excel-vba tag since we can set properties of the excel workbook using vba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Create linked table found in PowerPivot tab